# MPI call and receive in a nested loop

Tags: mpi

I have a nested loop and from inside the loop I call the MPI send which I want it to 
send to the receiver a specific value then at the receiver takes the data and again sends MPI messages 
to another set of CPUs ... I used something like this but it looks like there is a problem in the receive ... and I cant see where I went wrong ..."the machine goes to infinite loop somewhere ...

I am trying to make it work like this :
master CPU >> send to other CPUs >> send to slave CPUs

```
 . 
 . 
 . 

 int currentCombinationsCount; 
 int mp; 

 if (rank == 0)
 {


     for (int pr = 0; pr < combinationsSegmentSize; pr++)
     {
         int CblockBegin = CombinationsSegementsBegin[pr];
         int CblockEnd   = CombinationsSegementsEnd  [pr];
         currentCombinationsCount = numOfCombinationsEachLoop[pr]; 
         prossessNum = 1; //specify which processor we are sending to 

         // now substitute and send to the main Processors 
         for (mp = CblockBegin; mp <= CblockEnd; mp++)
         {

             MPI_Send(&mp , 1, MPI_INT   , prossessNum, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

             prossessNum ++; 
         }

     }//this loop goes through all the specified blocks for the combinations  
 } // end of rank 0
 else if (rank > currentCombinationsCount)
 {
       // here I want to put other receives that will take values from the else below 
 }
 else 
 {
     MPI_Recv(&mp , 1, MPI_INT   , 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
     // the code stuck here in infinite loop 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only initialised `currentCombinationsCount` within the `if(rank==0)` branch so all other procs will see an uninitialised variable. That will [result in undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value) and the outcome depends on your compiler. Your program may crash or the value may be set to 0 or an undetermined value.

If you're lucky, [the value may be set to 0](http://ideone.com/62Cm20) in which case your branch reduces to:

```
if (rank == 0) {  /* rank == 0 will enter this } 
else if (rank > 0) { /* all other procs enter this }
else { /* never entered! Recvs are never called to match the sends */ }
```

You therefore end up with sends that are not matched by any receives. Since [`MPI_Send` is potentially blocking](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/sendmode.html), the sending proc may stall indefinitely. With procs blocking on sends, it can certainly look as thought *"...the machine goes to infinite loop somewhere..."*.

If `currentCombinationsCount` is given an arbitrary value (instead of 0) then `rank!=0` procs will enter arbitrary branchss (with a higher chance of all entering the final `else`). You then end up with second set of receives not being called resulting in the same issue as above.

Comment: Thank you Shawn for answer but I am not using the currentCombinationsCount yet in anything ... I want to make sure that mp reached with the desired value in each iteration so I commented the currentCombinationsCount inside the loop and still the program stuck somewhere ... do you think there could be a logical problem ??

Comment: You are using it in your branch conditions, so yes it appears to be a problem with your program logic.